# Is it correct to say "the apple is soaked/stale/soggy with water"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

Sometimes, when I am in a supermarket, I see an apple whose some parts contain more water than the other parts.

This could be because sellers spray water on apples to keep them fresh and the water happens to leak into the apple. The water keeps staying there so long, and can not drain.

This also happens when I put a bag of apples or other fruits into my fridge. If I keep the fruits in the fridge so long, somehow some water licks into the fruits.

I hate eating these watery fruits, which taste  horrible.

I don't know what is the correct and common adjective to express that.

Is it correct to say "**the apple is soaked/stale/soggy with water**" or "**the apple is watery**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those suggestions sound idiomatic.

This may be more of a science matter than an English language matter, but I don't think an apple can *absorb* water. An apple's skin is waterproof and watertight - that's why they float in water. Your suggestions 'soaked' and 'soggy' generally imply that something has taken on water. 'Stale' tends to mean the opposite - foods that go bad from drying out, becoming dehydrated, (eg bread) tend to be called stale.

When dry things, such as bread, soak up water they may be called "soggy".

When fresh produce develops a watery consistency through the process of decomposition, we tend to say they have become **mushy**.

I don't believe the mushy fruit you are finding has taken on water that has been sprayed on it - the 'watery' nature of rotten fruit is due to the presence of water already in it. In the process of decomposition, or rotting, the fibres in the fruit break down and so it loses its fibrous texture. The same happens if you press fruit - the fibres break down and the juice comes out.

Comment: so a mushy fruit turns spoiled really quickly right?

Comment: @Tom "spoiled" is common in American English, not so much in British English (at least not for fruit/veg) where we tend to say something is "off" or has "gone off/bad". But yes, mushy fruit is on the verge of going bad / turning spoiled if not already that way.